# OneDrive photo icon deleted picture!

Tags: onedrive, pictures

So on my phone when I go into photos then into albums then click on the OneDrive file the screen looks like the picture I have added onto this.

[image]

The icon for the camera roll and the recent photos are pictures that have been deleted.

I have checked my OneDrive app many times to make sure the picture wasn't there anymore and I have deleted it from the trash bin, the picture no longer exist on my OneDrive app but somehow it's still being used as the icon.

Does anyone know how to fix this?!

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out.

Here's how to get rid of it: I went to Storage Sense App -- Phone -- Temporary Files --- Delete. IT WORKED!!!